# How to implement HATEOAS in a Spring-Boot microservices project

Tags: java, spring, rest, microservices, spring-hateoas

Lately I've been experimenting with building **microservices** using the Java **Spring Boot** framework. I currently have a working Microservices systeem with several resources (which all have its own independent service), e.g.: A Book service and a Review service.
Each service has its own **RestController** and uses a **MongoRepository** to interact with its database.

The end-users of the application (web-clients) will not communicate with these independent services itself but with an API above them.

This API calls the book and review services, merges the data and returns it back to the client. Note that all the communication is using `ResponseEntity<T>` (`T` can be `Book`, `Review`, `Iterable<Book>`, etc, ..)

But after reading a while I learnt about **HATEOAS** and I would like to use it in my microservices set-up. Now my question is, what is the best way to implement this?

Some examples I've found extend the entity classes (which in my case would be the Book entity or the Review entity with Spring's `ResourceSupport` class). But this causes errors since my entity's have an ID parameter and the `getId()` method clashes with the `getId()` method of the ResourceSupport class.

Other examples contain a `MongoRepository` annotated with `@RestResource` instead of using a **Controller**.

So my question is, what would in this case be the best way to implement HATEOAS? And e.g. when the Book service adds links (the HATEOAS way), how can the API above change these links? Since the end-users will only do calls to this API and the API just processes these requests and delegates it to the necesarry sub-services.

Comment: Have you looked into spring-data-rest? That will give you full HATEOAS support.

Comment: maybe start by reading [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/)

Comment: @anders That's what I did, but I can not extend my entities with the ResourceSupport class (like the Greeting class in the example) since my entities have an id and the getId() method clashes with the getId method of the ResourceSupport class

Comment: @ÁkosRatku it certainly looks promising. And for my lowest level services like Book and Review i certainly can use the `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation rather than using a controller. But the API's that connect these resources and aggregates them in to extended version of the base object classes need a controller (to process the Book and Review data results), so I can not use it there.

Comment: There is no limitation in `spring-data-rest` for custom controllers, check out the sample project : https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks . Also you don't need to extend any class to append links to your entity, you can wrap them into `Resource` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to have HATEOAS in place but do not want to use spring-data-rest you could still fall back to [Spring HATEOAS](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/)

It is internally used by spring-data-rest and gives you the ability to create a HATEOAS-style REST API.